# Extjs 7.4.0 - Remote Filtering problem with filter Operators

Tags: extjs

I am using gridfilterbar with remote filtering and there is a problem with any filter type with any filter operator. The filter param that is encoded for the service call, always has a default operator and can't recognize a different operator. My filter config is like this:

```
filter: {
    type: 'list',
    operators: ['=', '!='],
    options:  [0, 1, 2]
},
```

My solution for this problem was to override the Ext.data.proxy.Server and do a quick fix for the encodeFilters function. I check inside the loop that iterates through the filters and change the operator manually:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(filters[i].config.operator != filters[i]._operator){
            filters[i].config.operator = filters[i]._operator
        }
        encode |= filters[i].serializeTo(out);
    }
```

I am wondering if I missed something or if this is a bug that needs fixing.

Comment: Classic or Modern?

Comment: WIth classic toolkit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `opperators`, `opperator` works for me in this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3h979):

```
        columns: [{
            text: 'id',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            filter: {
                type: 'list',
                operator: ['!=='],
                options:  [0, 1, 2]
            }
        }, {
            text: 'name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            filter: 'string',
            flex: 1
        }]
```

Your examples do not show the use of several operators. Overall I guess you have to write your own custom filter (e.g. number, list,...), as this only works for remote filtering.
I would not override the Server proxy, but create a new filter.

Probably this Fiddle helps you to find a proper solution for your work. It has a custom store for the filter, which could replace your override:
[Fiddle 2](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3h6i)